# What are the Italian words that end with a consonant and that aren't inherited from other languages?

Tags: curiosity

I believe it is a very short list. Excluding words that are inherited, unchanged, from other languages (e.g. dessert).

Would it make sense to include "preposizioni articolate" (del, al, nel, col, etc) as they are shortened versions of (dello, della, allo, alla, nello, nella, etc.)?

Thank you.

Comment: ...and also the articles *il* and *un* and several prepositions (*in*, *con* etc.). It makes sense if it does for you, since you are the one asking the question!

Comment: Are words with Latin origin excluded? There is one very used lately: *referendum*!

Comment: Lots of words ending in *e* can appear in a version with 'troncamento': *fior*, *dolor*, *amar*. If you want a manageable list, I'd exclude truncated words, too.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Not only ending with *e*: *Nel mezzo del* cammin *di nostra vita*...

Comment: Indeed Federico, those excluded! and excluding Latin ones too.

Comment: @Wes What about words like *spider* that entered Italian through English but have a meaning completely unrelated to the English one? (In Italian *spider* means *convertible car*, probably from a confusion with *speeder*).

Comment: nice one Denis, that is indeed one!

Answer (score 7):

The Linux commands:

```
$ sudo apt install witalian
$ grep -i "^[^']*[^aeiouàèéìòù]$" /usr/share/dict/italian
```

(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression for info on the syntax used) return

```
BIOS
CD
Camerun
Cauchy
Cluny
Courmayeur
DOS
Debian
Dirac
Einstein
Emacs
FAQ
FSF
Feynman
Fidonet
Fourier
GPL
Galles
Galois
Gauss
GhostScript
HTML
HURD
Hegel
Intel
Internet
Kronecker
LISP
LaTeX
Linus
Linux
Lourdes
Madrid
Morgex
Murphy
Newton
Npc
Oliver
PC
POST
Pascal
Pentium
Planck
PostScript
SGML
Schwarzschild
Senegal
Stokes
TBC
TeX
Usenet
Vietnam
Windows
abbian
accusar
ad
addendum
al
alcol
alcool
alcun
alt
ananas
ancor
andar
apparir
aspettan
auditorium
autobus
aver
bazar
beh
bel
ben
biberon
bis
budget
buon
camion
cangiar
cantar
caos
chieder
ciascun
col
color
comprender
computer
con
conceder
correr
cracker
cuor
dal
dan
dar
deh
del
dicon
diesis
dimenticar
dir
don
dottor
dover
dovevan
ed
eh
ehm
emTeX
esser
est
facevan
fan
far
film
fin
fral
gas
gilet
goal
gran
gratis
hacker
han
idem
il
impedir
in
inox
iter
kg
lapis
lapsus
lasciar
laser
lavorar
maggior
mais
mal
management
men
metter
miglior
minor
morir
muor
muover
nel
nessun
non
nord
od
odor
offrir
onor
ovest
par
parer
particolar
per
poter
preferir
prevenir
proseguir
provenir
pur
qual
qualcun
quark
quel
quiz
ragion
ragionier
rayon
rebus
record
referendum
render
ribes
riempir
rifinir
rifornir
rifuggir
riveder
rivelan
salir
san
saper
saran
scoprir
seppur
signor
sin
slip
smaltir
smarrir
sol
son
spelling
sport
spray
stan
standard
star
stress
sub
sud
sul
suol
suon
super
svanir
tal
tandem
tener
termos
topless
toreador
trasalir
tunnel
uccider
un
unix
uscir
val
valzer
van
veder
venir
vien
virus
voler
vuol
zac
zenit
zic
```

Excluding proper names, 'troncamenti', and foreign words (but that's a personal judgement for many of them), I'd save

**ad, alcol, alt, beh, biberon, bis, bus** (e derivati), **camion, caos, con, deh, diesis, don, ed, eh, ehm, est, gas, in, lapis, mais, non, nord, od, ovest, per, quiz, record, ribes, sol** (la nota), **sport, stress, sud, super, tunnel, zac, zic**.

Comment: Great work! However, many of those you are indeed “inherited, unchanged, from other languages”, which the OP explicitly excluded: from biberon and camion to tunnel.

Comment: @DaG I didn't check every single one of them in the dictionary to make sure; feel free to edit the list in bold and remove those that do not belong.

Comment: are nord, sud, ovest, est found in other languages? maybe latin? thanks!

Comment: @Wes You can check on https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nord (and similarly for the other three).

Comment: @Wes *Nord, sud, ovest, est* are of Germanic origin, but there are a lot of words of Germanic origin in Italian (e.g. *guerra*) and I'd say that these words are as Italian as they can be. Also, what are your feelings about words like *quorum* that come from Latin, but have a completely different meaning in Italian?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, perhaps I am too strict, but I'd remove most of them. biberon, camion, gas, ... come from French; bus, quiz, record, sport, stress, tunnel are unadapted English words; and so on. These word have the same status as dessert, which the OP excludes. On the other hand, the OP should describe better the boundaries of the words he is interested in. For instance, *alt* comes from German *halt* (i.e., “stop!”): is it acceptable because it is not equal to the German form?

Comment: For me *bus* comes from latin.

Comment: *Zig-zag* is left (from French)...

Comment: @CarLaTeX: «bus1 ‹bḁs› s. **ingl.** (pl. buses ‹bḁ′si∫›), usato in ital. al masch. – Accorciamento di *omnibus*, correntemente usato col sign. di «autobus», con cui è comune anche in Italia (di solito pronunciato ‹bus›) [...]» ([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bus1/))

Comment: @DaG but doesn't the English *bus* come from Latin?

Comment: Indeed, @CarLaTeX. In this sense, with one or more intermediate passages, all of *quiz*, *record*, *sport*, *stress* come from Latin (as do most French words). Nevertheless, *bus* is a word Italian borrowed from English.