# Are there any rules that italian words needs to end with vowel characters?

Tags: grammar

I've heard before that in italiano, the real italian words ends with a vowel character. So that I can understand if a word ends with a vowel character, it can be belongs to italiano. For example:

toast = not italiano
pane tostato = italiano

Is this rule really exists for italian grammar?

Comment: In other words... are words ending with a consonant  non-Italian by definition?  Correct?

Comment: Yes definitely.

Comment: I think the real question is... why do all or the vast majority of Italian words end with vowels?  Vowels denote gender and number.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related: http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/7729/what-are-the-italian-words-that-end-with-a-consonant-and-that-arent-inherited-f

Comment: I doubt there is such a grammatical rule, since truncation is *very* common in Italian (e.g. *Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita*; *Un bel tacer non fu mai scritto* etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of words in Italian that end in consonant, but they are mostly coming from Latin/Greek/Other or are contractions of other words (or articles/particles). But while their origin is foreign, they are not simply "loan words", but proper parts of the language:

Tram, pancreas, Nord Sud Ovest Est, Un, il, gratis, gas, etc...

So, according to where you draw the line, all "Italian" words end in vowel. But articles are a prime example of non-loan words/foreign origin that don't, if you count them as words

I'd like to point your attention to [this quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Are-Telugu-and-Italian-the-only-languages-in-the-world-with-all-words-ending-with-a-vowel-sound/answer/Andr%C3%A9-M%C3%BCller-1?srid=7zjv), in particular, which describes the topic in details.

Comment: Tram is an abbreviation of tramvia

Comment: All Italian words have a foreign origin under those criteria, simply because Italian was not created from thin air.